# How to convert [AnyHashable: Any] to NSmutableDictionary

Tags: swift, objective-c

As stated in the title, how to convert [AnyHashable: Any] to nsmutabledictionary?
I need to do some Obj-c to Swift relation.

Comment: Post the code you tried and the errors you got please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very straight forward

```
var d = [AnyHashable: Any]()
d["name"] = "Jay"
d[0] = "Jay"
print(d)
//[AnyHashable(0): "Jay", AnyHashable("name"): "Jay"]


let nsD = NSDictionary(dictionary: d)
print(nsD)
//{
//    0 = Jay;
//    name = Jay;
//}


let nsMD = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: d)
print(nsMD)
//{
//    0 = Jay;
//    name = Jay;
//}
```

Bridging example:

Your swift class may look like this

```
@objc class Swft: NSObject {
    @objc var d = [AnyHashable: Any]()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        d["name"] = "jay"
    }
    
    @objc func method() ->[AnyHashable: Any] {
        return d
    }
}
```

And your Objective-C class may look like this, `.m`

```
#import "Objc.h"
#import "{Your_project_name}-Swift.h"

@interface Objc ()

@end

@implementation Objc

- (void)someMethod {
    
    Swft *s = [[Swft alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"1234567890 %@", s.d);
//    1234567890 {
//        name = jay;
//    }
    NSLog(@"0987654321 %@", [s method]);
//    0987654321 {
//        name = jay;
//    }

}

@end
```